# Need to use awk to get a specific word or value after another specific word?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to use awk to get a specific word or value after another specific word, I tried some awk commands already but after many other filters like grep and sed. The file that I need to get the word from is having the same line more than one time like the below line:

```
Configuration: number=6 model=MSA SNT=4 IC=8 SIZE=16384MB NRF=24 meas=2.00
```

If need 24 I used

```
grep IC file | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}'
```

If need 16384MB I used

```
grep IC file | awk -F'SIZE=' '{ print $2 }'|awk '{ print $1 }'
```

We need to get any word from that line using awk? what I used can get what is needed but we still need a minimized awk command.

I am sure we can use one single awk to get the needed info from one line minimized command?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r  's/.*SIZE=([^ ]+).*/\1/' input
16384MB
sed -r  's/.*NRF=([^ ]+).*/\1/' input
24
```

`grep`  way :

```
grep -oP 'SIZE=\K[^ ]+' imput
16384MB
```

`awk` way :

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /SIZE=/) split($i,a,"=");print a[2]}' input
```

Comment: sed: Not a recognized flag: r
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]
It's AIX box

Comment: try `sed  's/.*SIZE=\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/'` , here we have to manually escape .

Comment: I got the whole line !

Comment: then go for `awk` :
`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /SIZE=/) split($i,a,"=");print a[2]}' input`

Comment: or grep `grep -oP 'SIZE=\K[^ ]+' input`

Comment: i got the expected result but repeated in rows with the same number of file rows !

Comment: It's not the expcted usage from grep as well @AIX

Comment: any idea if awk -F can be used?

Comment: I used awk -F "meas=" '/meas\=/ {print $NF}' file and got what is needed however that worked only for the last value in the line I still can't get the others ? any idea?

Comment: @mshafey: may be my answer could help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `Awk` with multi-character de-limiter as below to get this done. Loop through the fields, match the *pattern* you need and print the next field which contains the field value.

```
awk -F'[:= ]' -v option="${match}" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ option) {print $(i+1)}}' file
```

Examples,

```
match="number"
awk -F'[:= ]' -v option="${match}" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ option) {print $(i+1)}}' file
6

match="model"
awk -F'[:= ]' -v option="${match}" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ option) {print $(i+1)}}' file
MSA

match="meas"
awk -F'[:= ]' -v option="${match}" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ option) {print $(i+1)}}' file
2.00
```

Comment: Why are you using match? You could just use `$i~match`.

Comment: @123: done, but my guess is there is nothing much radically different performance-wise, do correct me if am wrong

Comment: It's perfect however the last value had 3 blank rows after it in the output and for some reason they do need another minimized? they think the line is somewhat big ...

Comment: @mshafey: I wouldn't worry about how big the command looks, if it works flawlessly. There is no use in having short/un reliable commands. I would prefer working commands

Comment: I agree with that however they don't ! and the last value issue still there ... check above comment

Comment: What is the issue that you are talking about?

Comment: the last value had 3 blank rows after it in the output

Comment: @mshafey: That is because of your file had multiple has multiple such-lines? If multiple lines are there, do you need all values to be shown? Please update the question if that is the case

Comment: @mshafey Change `'{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` to `'/IC/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` as you are grepping for that in your question.

Comment: @123: Fair point, honestly I thought it wouldn't make a difference since OP had one line in the file. But not sure if there are multiple lines containing with (or) without pattern

Answer (score 1):

here is a more general approach

```
... | awk -v k=NRF '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,a,"="); m[a[1]]=a[2]} print m[k]}'
```

code will stay the same just change the key `k`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU awk you could use the third parameter of `match`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/( IC=)([^ ]*)/,a)&&  $0=a[2]' file
8
```

Or get the `meas`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/( meas=)([^ ]*)/,a)&&  $0=a[2]' file
2.00
```

Should you use some other awk, you could use this combination of `split`, `substr` and `match`:

```
$ awk 'split(substr($0,match($0,/ IC=[^ ]*/),RLENGTH),a,"=") &&  $0=a[2]' file
8
```

Comment: @123 No, he hasn't. And if he did it in the comments, you should instruct him not to.

Comment: Meant to say answer not question, it is in the comments on PS's. Also why should I?

Comment: @123 To quote my favorite movie _Full Metal Jacket_: _Private Pyle has dishonored himself and dishonored the platoon. I have tried to help him. But I have failed. I have failed because YOU have not helped me. YOU people have not given Private Pyle the proper motivation! So, from now on, whenever Private Pyle ***** up, I will not punish him! I will punish all of YOU! And the way I see it ladies, you owe me for ONE JELLY DOUGHNUT! NOW GET ON YOUR FACES!_ :D